# Fifo was never created

Tags: c, linux, fifo

I have the follow code:
    ...

```
umask(0);
unlink(FIFO_FILE);
if(mknod(FIFO_FILE, S_IFIFO|0666, 0)==-1){

  perror("mknod");
}
printf("Servidor iniciado.\nEm modo de espera de mensagens\n");


while(1){

    fp = fopen(FIFO_FILE, "r");
```

my problem is that open never works cause the Fifo's never was created!

UPDATE: output: mknod: Operation not permitted

Comment: Add checks for `mknod` return value if it fails, preferrable with `perror` call to get actual error

Comment: mknod: Operation not permitted

Comment: `EPERM`: ... also returned if the filesystem containing pathname does not support the type of node requested.
from http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mknod.2.html

Comment: after calling `perror()` to display the error resulting from the call to `mknode()`, then call `exit()`.   Do not be trying to use that fifo node as it does not exist so the looping call to `fopen()` will always fail.

Comment: what is the char string pointed to by the varaible `FIFO_FILE`?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I 'have trier to create a pipe in a folder shared between my virtual box and windows and windows created the problem so I change folder location and so its solved

Comment: please accept your answer so this question can be closed.